# Split on all unescaped semicolons

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript-string which contains semicolons (some of them are escaped).

My problem is, how do I split this string on all unescaped semicolons and leave the escaped ones

```
var example = "abc;def;ghi\;jk"
```

This should get:

```
example[0] = "abc";
example[1] = "def";
example[2] = "ghi\;jk";
```

I only found a PHP-regex, which is not working in javascript :(

```
'/(?<!\\\);/'
```

any ideas how to do this?

Comment: well the example string would have to look like `"abc;def;ghi\\;jk"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript has no negative look-behind (which would make this problem simple), so we can emulate it by reversing the string and using negative look-ahead!

```javascript
function splitByUnescapedSemicolons(s) {
  var rev = s.split('').reverse().join('');
  return rev.split(/;(?=[^\\])/g).reverse().map(function(x) {
    return x.split('').reverse().join('');
  });
}

splitByUnescapedSemicolons("abc;def;ghi\;jk"); // => ["abc", "def", "ghi\;jk"]
```

Comment: @user1689607: what's your solution look like?

Comment: Getting the index of the next `;`, and testing the previous character for the `\ `, then slicing the string from the previous index to the current if there was no `\ `.

Comment: Does not correctly handle case where semicolon is preceded by an escaped escape, i.e. `"abc;def;ghi\\;jk"`

Answer (score 2):

The following tested JavaScript function does the trick:

### Semicolon Separated Values:

```js
function splitByUnescapedSemicolons(text) {
    var a = [];                 // Array to receive results.
    if (text === '') return a;  // Special empty string case.
    // Push first (possibly last) value.
    text = text.replace(/^[^;\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^;\\]*)*(?=;|$)/,
        function(m0){a.push(m0); return '';});
    // Push any 2nd, 3rd, remaining values.
    text = text.replace(/;([^;\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^;\\]*)*)/g,
        function(m0, m1){a.push(m1); return '';});
    return a;
}
```

This solution correctly handles escaped semicolons (and escaped anything else too, including escaped-escapes).

### Example data:

```js
"" == [];
";" == ['', ''];
"\;" == ['\;'];
"\\;" == ['\\', ''];
"one;two" == ['one', 'two'];
"abc;def;ghi\;jk" == ['abc', 'def', 'ghi\;jk'];
"abc;def;ghi\\;jk" == ['abc', 'def', 'ghi\\', 'jk'];
```